# Why wont my function draw multiple bricks?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this simple function that should show multiple bricks, but it only shows one. Anyone knows why? I doesn't show any errors.

```js
function drawbricks() {

  for (var r = 0; r < 12; r++) {

    for (var c = 0; c < 6; c++) {

      var posix = r + 20;
      var posiy = c + 20;

      ctx.fillRect(posix, posiy, 50, 50);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give some more details i mean the page where you want to show the bricks. You can add them as a snippet

Comment: They're offset by a single pixel--won't they just be on top of each other? Maybe try *multiplying* instead of adding, and make the bricks smaller than the offset.

Comment: `ctx` is undefined here.  Please add the code where you assign it.

Answer (score 1):

I've added some constants so you can configure your bricks.

```js
const c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
drawbricks(ctx);

function drawbricks(ctx) {
  const brickCountRows = 10;
  const brickCountColumns = 15;
  const brickWidth = 20;
  const brickHeight = 10;
  const brickSpacingX = 2;
  const brickSpacingY = 2;

  for (var r = 0; r < brickCountRows; r++) {
    for (var c = -1; c < brickCountColumns; c++) { // start at -1 to fill gap caused by offset (see below)
      var posix = c * (brickWidth + brickSpacingX); // switched r by c (column is x component)
      var posiy = r * (brickHeight + brickSpacingY); // switched c by r (row is y component)
      
      // offset every other row by half brickWidth + brickSpacing
      if (r%2 == 1) {
        posix += Math.floor((brickWidth + brickSpacingX)/2)
      }

      ctx.fillRect(posix, posiy, brickWidth, brickHeight);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you ment to multiply the coordinates instead of adding.

```
  var posix = r * 20;
  var posiy = c * 20;
```

But still, the "bricks" will overlay each other.

Comment: yeah after posting the question i changed to multiply, and it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Elena The bricks are larger than the offset.

Comment: @Elena post the whole code then. Cant help you if we can't run your code.